# Expression predicate must be built separately with if and else blocks?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have 2 versions of codes for class method "GetUserRoles".  Version 1 always works OK while Version 2 is not working if passed-in argument "**exludeRoleNames**" for that method is ***absent*** and exception "**Null object reference**" is thrown as a result.  I would like to understand why Version 2 codes are not always working, and why Version 1 codes require building predicate with "if" and "else" blocks. Thank you in advance.

**Version 1:**
The following codes are always working. You could notice that there are separate "if" and "else" blocks to build local variable `Expression<Func<UserRoleInApplication, bool>> predicate`

```
public List<UserInRoleViewModel> GetUserRoles(long userId, params string[] exludeRoleNames)
        {
            List<UserInRoleViewModel> results = null;
            IQueryable<UserInRoleViewModel> items = null;


            Expression<Func<UserRoleInApplication, bool>> predicate = null;

            if (exludeRoleNames.Count() <= 0)
            {
                predicate = x => true;
            }
            else
            {
                predicate = x => !exludeRoleNames.Contains(x.UserRole.RoleName);
            }

            items = from uir in _repository.GetQuery<UserInRole>(x => x.UserId == userId)
                    join ura in _repository.GetQuery<UserRoleInApplication>(predicate)
                            on uir.UserRoleInApplicationId equals ura.UserRoleInApplicationId
                            into g
                    from item in g
                    select new UserInRoleViewModel
                    {
                        UserInRoleId = uir.UserInRoleId,
                        UserId = uir.UserId,
                        UserRoleInApplicationId = uir.UserRoleInApplicationId
                    };


            if (items != null && items.Any())
            {
                results = new List<UserInRoleViewModel>();
                results = items.ToList();
            }

            return results;
       }
```

**Version 2:**
However, the following codes throw exception "Null object reference" when calling method GetUserRoles such as  GetUserRoles(long userId) ***without passed-in argument*** "exludeRoleNames". You could notice that there are **no** separate "if" and "else" blocks for the codes to form local variable `Expression<Func<UserRoleInApplication, bool>> predicate`:

```
    public List<UserInRoleViewModel> GetUserRoles(long userId, params string[] exludeRoleNames)
            {
                List<UserInRoleViewModel> results = null;
                IQueryable<UserInRoleViewModel> items = null;

 // Note: one line code and no separate "if" and "else" blocks *************
                Expression<Func<UserRoleInApplication, bool>> predicate = x => exludeRoleNames.Count() <= 0 ? true : !exludeRoleNames.Contains(x.UserRole.RoleName);


                items = from uir in _repository.GetQuery<UserInRole>(x => x.UserId == userId)
                        join ura in _repository.GetQuery<UserRoleInApplication>(predicate)
                                on uir.UserRoleInApplicationId equals ura.UserRoleInApplicationId
                                into g
                        from item in g
                        select new UserInRoleViewModel
                        {
                            UserInRoleId = uir.UserInRoleId,
                            UserId = uir.UserId,
                            UserRoleInApplicationId = uir.UserRoleInApplicationId
                        };


                if (items != null && items.Any()) // Note: throw exception "Null object reference" if parameter "exludeRoleNames" is absent on calling method GetUserRoles such as  GetUserRoles(long userId);
                {
                    results = new List<UserInRoleViewModel>();
                    results = items.ToList();
                }

                return results;
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
Expression<Func<UserRoleInApplication, bool>> predicate = x => exludeRoleNames.Count() <= 0 ? true : !exludeRoleNames.Contains(x.UserRole.RoleName);
```

To this:

```
Expression<Func<UserRoleInApplication, bool>> predicate = x => true;
if(exludeRoleNames != null)
{
    foreach(string exl in exludeRoleNames)
    {    
        string temp = exl;
        predicate = predicate.Or(x=>x.UserRole.RoleName == temp);
    }
}
```

The problem is that you're trying to call Count() on exludeRoleNames - which is null.  So, rather than check Count(), compare it to null.  If it is null, then you can treat it as an empty array.  If it isn't null, then check it's contents.

The other problem is that you can't use string[].Contains in a query context.  Entity Framework (which I assume you are using) doesn't support that.  So, you have to build out the predicate.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I followed your hint, but I got an exception like "Cannot compare elements of type 'System.String[]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported."  Any ideas?

Comment: I missed that this was being used in a query.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I re-write the following codes and they are working. In case of absent parameter "exludeRoleNames",  the codes creat an empty string array:

```
public List<UserInRoleViewModel> GetUserRoles(long userId, params string[] exludeRoleNames)
            {
                List<UserInRoleViewModel> results = null;
            IQueryable<UserInRoleViewModel> items = null;

            exludeRoleNames = !exludeRoleNames.Any() ? new string[] { } : exludeRoleNames; // a MUST
            Expression<Func<UserRoleInApplication, bool>> predicate = x => !exludeRoleNames.Contains(x.UserRole.RoleName);

            items = from uir in _repository.GetQuery<UserInRole>(x => x.UserId == userId)
                    join ura in _repository.GetQuery<UserRoleInApplication>(predicate)
                            on uir.UserRoleInApplicationId equals ura.UserRoleInApplicationId
                            into g
                    from item in g
                    select new UserInRoleViewModel
                    {
                        UserInRoleId = uir.UserInRoleId,
                        UserId = uir.UserId,
                        UserRoleInApplicationId = uir.UserRoleInApplicationId
                    };

            if (items != null && items.Any())
            {
                results = new List<UserInRoleViewModel>();
                results = items.ToList();
            }

            return results;
           }
```